Power harvesting from NFC device(smartphone)
I want to design a circuit that can read data from a sensor (this is a color sensor ,AS7341) and it will be connected to a LED. But I want the circuit to be lightweight and don't want to use a battery. I want to wirelessly get the sensor reading from the device to the smartphone, it will just be a one time reading with NFC. I was wondering if there are any microcontrollers that can harvest energy from the smartphone and perform this task? Will it be enough to power up the microcontroller, led and the color sensor? I just want to know if this is something feasible or not. If so, what are my options?

This reminds me of something a mechanical engineer asked me the other day: "Is it possible to have a wireless charger but have instead of it charging the device, it actually takes away from said device?" Yes, you could technically do this but it might be equally sophisticated and likely requires inductive coupling.

You say "oh there's an LED" but you don't explain what this highly power-hungry device needs to do.  If you have an LED in there, then the microprocessor isn't your biggest worry.  You may want to edit your question to "how do I figure out whether my application will work with NFC".  While you're doing that, be clear about whether you're talking about cell phone NFC, or some other variety.

@TimWescott I edited my question according to your suggestions. Can you please explain why this would be a highly power-hungry device? I want to determine the light intensity of the LED using AS7341 (which requires 1.8V for operation, max 300µA consumption) and I'll use an led (HSMW-C230) which has a forward current of 5 mA with a typical forward voltage of 2.85 V. Is this feasible with an NFC power harvesting IC like the NTAG I²C Plus by NXP?

What you are describing is exactly how contactless smart cards (“chip and pin” payment cards for instance) work: the reader provides enough power for the (tiny) controller in the card to power up, perform crypto operations, exchange data, etc.
There are also e-ink NFC-powered screens using the same principle: the reader (the phone in this instance) powers up the micro-controller and the screen during the time the new screen contents are sent. See here or here for instance.
It would also be possible to store some of that energy to use after the NFC reader is gone, but it won’t be much in a standard NFC interaction (though the principle is that of wireless charging, I.e Qi or MagSafe, which just provide a much larger power budget — but currently few phones will allow power to be transferred out, only in).
In pure NFC, the whole issue is to stay within the (pretty low) power budget. The exact budget will vary based on a number of parameters such as distance, size of the “antenna” (coil, really), etc. You’ll need a low-power micro-controller, and carefully select your sensor.
I can’t find actual figures of how much power you can draw using “standard” NFC from a phone, but I suspect the sensor you quote may be a little bit too power-hungry, so you may need to switch to another one, or alternatively need to accumulate a bit of energy (e.g. in a capacitor or supercap) before turning the sensor on. The details (how long you’ll have to hold the device to your phone to get a reading) will vary based on how much energy (power x time) you need.

I want to determine the light intensity of the LED using AS7341 (which requires 1.8V for operation, max 300µA consumption) and I'll use an led (HSMW-C230) which has a forward current of 5 mA with a typical forward voltage of 2.85 V. Is this feasible with a NFC power harvesting IC like the NTAG I²C Plus by NXP?

@SamihaAhmed the data sheet says it will typically provide 5 mA @ 2V (with all the usual caveats). That seems to be too little for powering the LED directly (LEDs in general are quite power hungry), but depending on how long on you need it on and how long you are ready to wait, you could store energy in a cap or supercap for a moment before your use power from it, as explained in the answer.
